# Relative compactness in $L^p\left(0,\frac{T}{2};B\right)$ and $L^p\left(\frac{T}{2},T;B\right)$ gives relative compactness in $L^p\left(0,T;B\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $B$ be a Banach-space. And let $L^p\left(0,T;B\right)$ be the space of all Lebesgue integrable functions $f:[0,T] \rightarrow B$. I want to show:
If $F \subset L^p\left(0,\frac{T}{2};B\right)$ is relatively compact in $L^p\left(0,\frac{T}{2};B\right)$ and if $F$ is relatively compact in $L^p\left(\frac{T}{2},T;B\right)$, then $F$ is relatively compact in $L^p(0,T;B)$.

I tried to prove it by using that in Banach-spaces total boundedness is equivalent to relative compactness. So because $F$ is relatively compact in $L^p\left(0,\frac{T}{2};B\right)$ it holds that:

For every $\varepsilon>0$ one finds a finite subset $A := \{f_i : 1 \leq i \leq J\} \subset F$, such that for every $f \in F$ there exists a $f_i \in A$, such that $\Vert f - f_i \Vert_{L^p\left(0,\frac{T}{2};B\right)} \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2^{\frac{1}{p}}}$.

Because $F$ is relatively compact in $L^p\left(\frac{T}{2},T;B\right)$ it holds that:

For every $\varepsilon>0$ one finds a finite subset $B := \{g_j : 1 \leq j \leq K\} \subset F$, such that for every $f \in F$ there exists a $g_j \in B$, such that $\Vert f - g_j \Vert_{L^p\left(\frac{T}{2},T;B\right)} \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2^{\frac{1}{p}}}$.

Now let $\varepsilon >0$ be arbitrary 
and take the finite subset $E := A \cup B \subset F $ and define $l_k \in E$ as follows:
\begin{equation*}
l_k(x) :=\begin{cases}
     f_i(x) & \text{for } x \in [0,\frac{T}{2}) \\
     g_j(x) & \text{for } x \in [\frac{T}{2},T]
   \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Then we have that for every $ f\in F$ there exists a $l_k \in E$, such that
\begin{align*}
\left(\int_0^T \Vert f-l_k \Vert_B^p \ dt \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} &= \left(\int_0^{\frac{T}{2}} \Vert f-f_i \Vert_B^p \ dt+\int_{\frac{T}{2}}^T \Vert f-g_j \Vert_B^p \ dt \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \\&\leq \left(\frac{\varepsilon^p}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon^p}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} = \varepsilon.
\end{align*}

The problem is that I do not know wether $l_k \in F$. So the proof is not correct. Does anyone know how to save the proof or has a different approach?

Comment: Your definition of $L^p$ is wrong. And the question makes no sense: If $F\subset L^p(),\frac T2;B)$ then $F$ is not even a subset of $L^p(\frac T2, T;B)$, so it certainly can't be relatively compact in $L^p(\frac T2, T;B)$.

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent definition of relative compactness of a subset $F$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is that for all positive $\varepsilon$, there exists a finite subset $F'$ of $X$ such that $F\subset \bigcup_{x\in F'}B(x,\varepsilon)$.

Indeed, if $F$ satisfies the later definition, for all $x\in F'$, pick $y_x\in B(x,\varepsilon)\cap F$ (we can assume that this set is not empty, otherwise we simply remove this $x\in F'$ without changing veracity of the inclusion  $\bigcup_{x\in F'}B(x,\varepsilon)$). Then $F\subset \bigcup_{x\in F'}B\left(y_x,2\varepsilon\right)$: indeed, let $z\in F$. There exists $x\in F$ such that $d(x,z)\lt \varepsilon$. And $d\left(x,y_x\right)\lt \varepsilon$.

Therefore, in the context of your problem, you do not have to worry whether $l_k$ is in $F$ or not.